# Could not cast value of type PageViewController to another Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

hello I have  ViewController which is connected through segue to **UIPageViewController** and also in ViewController there are two buttons which are connected to the another controller(**LoginSignupViewController**) through segue. The buttons name are Login and Register. both the login and register buttons have different segue identifiers. I am getting an error while clicking the Login Button or register button

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "loginSegue") {

        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! LoginSignupViewController

        secondViewController.navigationTitle = "LOGIN"

    }else if (segue.identifier == "registerSegue") {

        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! LoginSignupViewController

        secondViewController.navigationTitle = "SIGN UP"
        //etc...
    }

}
```

If I compile app using this code.. I get this

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' reason: '-[__NSCFType set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

so I removed if else condition and compiled the app using this code

```
let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as!   LoginSignupViewController

    secondViewController.navigationTitle = "LOGIN"
```

I get this error

```
 Could not cast value of type 'Myproject.PageViewController' (0x10008c550) to 'MyProject.LoginSignupViewController' (0x10008c0f0).
```

when I printed out `print(segue.identifier)`

It print this on console

```
Optional("pageViewController")
```

My storyboard screenshot

[image]

NOTE: THE CODE WORKS FINE ON IOS 9 OR GREATER. The app crashes on IOS 8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debug the code and I find out the app was crashing because in viewdid load function of destination controller, I have added some code which don't  work for IOS 8. I didn't bother to debug  destination controller code because the error was ambiguous as it was giving me type casting errors. Thanks for all of your help and time to all of you. I am writing here in case if anyone get this error in future, he should check another destination controller code too.

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. You should keep if-else condition. You should do like this:

**1** Put `var stringTitle: String!` to `LoginSignupViewController`

**2** Change code in `prepareSegue` to:

```
if (segue.identifier == "loginSegue") {

    let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! LoginSignupViewController

    secondViewController.stringTitle = "LOGIN"

}else if (segue.identifier == "registerSegue") {

    let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! LoginSignupViewController

    secondViewController.stringTitle = "SIGN UP"
    //etc...
}
```

**3** In `viewDidLoad` of `LoginSignupViewController` put code:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "LOGIN"
```

Comment: @hellosheikh and still crash?

Comment: yes.. the code works fine on IOS 9.. it got crash in ios 8.4

Comment: @hellosheikh what about `secondViewController.navigationTitle`?

Comment: sorry I am not getting you ?

Comment: I mean that what is kind of `navigationTitle`

Comment: oh I am changing the navigation title on another controller based on which button is pressed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97621/discussion-between-vien-vu-and-hellosheikh).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "loginSegue" is pointing to your `LoginSignupViewController`? Your second error is indicating that `destinationViewController` is actually a `PageViewController`, and the crash is happening because you are forcefully trying to cast it to a `LoginSignupViewController`.